# Long running operation in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm implementing a long running call for my spring-mvc application. Here's how the call look like:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/generate")
public void longOperation(HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    //do heavy calculation
    Object jobResult;
    while (...) {
        //do job    
    }

    //output result
    response.getOutputStream().println(jobResult.toString());
}
```

During a while call I make a heavy in-memory computations (5+ mins). I do not write anything in output stream. Once computations are done, I put a result to output stream. The result is small (a few bytes).

However, if the user decide to cancel HTTP-call (close browser, or terminate curl session) I want to cancel computations as well. Ideally the code should look like:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/generate")
public void longOperation(HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    //do heavy calculation
    Object jobResult;
    while (...) {
        //do job
        if (userHasCancelledTheCall) return;    
    }

    //output result
    response.getOutputStream().println(jobResult.toString());
}
```

One way to achieve that would be trying to write something to response.getOutputStream(). If user closed HTTP-connection the attempt would throw an exception. However, I don't want to write anything there.

Is there a way how to check if response connection is still alive and it's worth continue making calculations?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you absolutely want the user to wait on a blank white screen for 5 minutes? My thought would be to make the call asynchronous and return and ID for the call immediately. Then a separate function to cancel the operation based on ID

Comment: Yes, I want the user to wait. It's an internal interface and most users will do curl console call anyway.

Comment: Ok and if they leave the page or cancel you want it to cancel the operation? Do you want to rollback the changes that were made up until that time?

Comment: If you answer the following question I will spend a lot of time giving you a thorough answer. Check my Liferay answers I spend a lot of time on them

Comment: @ChrisMaggiulli thanks for you help. It's nothing to cancel, really. The code does only read-only operations, such as: download data from database via REST API and do a compute-intensive calculations over that data in memory

Comment: So basically you have an operation that is long running and does a variety of reads (no updates). When a user "cancels" the request by Ctrl+c the curl request you want it to terminate?  If atomicity is not something you're worried about why do you care if it cancels or not?  If the user cancels the cURL request and the servers thread continues to execute why does it matter if there are no records being updated? I'm just clarifying before I provide some code

Comment: The only reason I want to cancel an operation is a CPU-resources. The operations consumes a lot of CPU. A number of user can use the API at the same time. If one of them cancelled the operations, I want to free resources for others.

Comment: Got it. I'll post my answer today